# Align list items left on a row with huge height

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a list component filled with text of varying length.

I currently have this
[image]

But I'm trying to get this
[image]

And is it possible to manually wrap the row height depending on the size of the text inside the row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom renderer like this:

```
<mx:Box verticalAlign="top">
    <mx:Label id="text"/>
</mx:Box>
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    //fill text from data
}
```